# Prevent recyclerview from refreshing items when an item is added

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display the total results (total item) in a RecyclerView. The items of the RecyclerView may vary based on the filter selected by the user. The problem is that when I changed something in the Firestore database, the total item counts are not based on the filter results anymore, instead, Firestore returns the total items in the entire collection.

```
private void load() {
    Query query = createQuery();
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Student> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Student>()
            .setQuery(query, Student.class)
            .build();

    myStudentAdapter = new MyStudentAdapter(options) {
        @Override
        public void onDataChanged() {
            super.onDataChanged();
            tv_total.setText(String.valueOf(getItemCount()));
        }
    };

    rv.setAdapter(myStudentAdapter);
    myStudentAdapter.startListening();
}

private Query createQuery() {
    if (!search.isEmpty()) {
        if (!course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course)
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year)
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block)
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        } else if (!course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course)
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year)
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        } else if (!course.isEmpty() && year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course)
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block)
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        } else if (course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year)
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block)
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        } else if (!course.isEmpty() && year.isEmpty() && block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course)
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        } else if (course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year)
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        } else if (course.isEmpty() && year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block)
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        } else {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        }
    } else {
        if (!course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course)
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year)
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block);
        } else if (!course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course)
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year);
        } else if (!course.isEmpty() && year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course)
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block);
        } else if (course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year)
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block);
        } else if (!course.isEmpty() && year.isEmpty() && block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course);
        } else if (course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year);
        } else if (course.isEmpty() && year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block);
        } else {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to display the total results (total item) in a RecyclerView.

If you want to know the total number of documents a query returns, then you have to call [count()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#count()) on a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query) object, which:

> Returns a query that counts the documents in the result set of this query.

If you need that count inside your adapter class, then you have to override [getItemCount()](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/5b6c9f01f5a674d754d8e9b1242197fe040086e7/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java#L95) that exists inside the `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` class which:

> return the total count of snapshots in the adapter.

If you need to refresh the results once you pass another query to your `options` object, then you have to call [updateOptions(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions options)](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/5b6c9f01f5a674d754d8e9b1242197fe040086e7/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java#L103) in order to take effect.

Comment: Where should I put the updateOptions method?

Comment: You should call it on your adapter object.

Comment: I use the adapter object to call the updateOptions() method but it returns 0.

Comment: Most likely you're passing a query that returns no documents, or you aren't starting to listen for changes correctly.

Comment: I override tha onDataChanged() method of FirestoreRecyclerOptions. At first it returns 6 (total students in my db) then I did a filter to return students only from specific course like BSCS, it returns 1 (which is correct) but when I changed something in the database, the RecyclerView was refreshed and the total items are now 6 (which is incorrect)..it should remain 1

Comment: Without seeing the code that you're using right now, I cannot be much of a help. So if you have a hard time implementing the solution in my answer, then please post a new question here, on StackOverflow in which you should show us everything you have tried. In this way, I or other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: @VinceYbañez Which list are you passing to the adapter? May be the list with all items. Make a separate list or perform the filter before you count the items.

Comment: @FahadBinAsif I am using FirestoreRecyclerOptions (FirestoreUI) so I don't have to work with list

Comment: Hey @AlexMamo I've created a new question related to my question. Can you please help me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74719809/how-to-prevent-firestore-from-resetting-query-ondatachanged)?

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.

Comment: Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information regarding this issue?