# How to prevent firestore from resetting Query data onDataChanged?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, I added a filter functionality where I can get all students from a specific course and display the total results. The problem is that when I change something in the database, the total results displayed is not based on the query anymore.

```
private void load() {
    Query query = createQuery();
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Student> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Student>()
            .setQuery(query, Student.class)
            .build();

    myStudentAdapter = new MyStudentAdapter(options){
        @Override
        public void onDataChanged() {
            super.onDataChanged();
            tv_total.setText(String.valueOf(getItemCount()));
        }
    };
    rv.setAdapter(myStudentAdapter);
    myStudentAdapter.startListening();
}

private Query createQuery() {
    if (!search.isEmpty()) {
        if (!course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course)
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year)
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block)
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        } else if (!course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course)
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year)
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        } else if (!course.isEmpty() && year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course)
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block)
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        } else if (course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year)
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block)
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        } else if (!course.isEmpty() && year.isEmpty() && block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course)
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        } else if (course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year)
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        } else if (course.isEmpty() && year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block)
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        } else {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .startAt(search)
                    .endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
        }
    } else {
        if (!course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course)
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year)
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block);
        } else if (!course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course)
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year);
        } else if (!course.isEmpty() && year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course)
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block);
        } else if (course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year)
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block);
        } else if (!course.isEmpty() && year.isEmpty() && block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("course", course);
        } else if (course.isEmpty() && !year.isEmpty() && block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("year", year);
        } else if (course.isEmpty() && year.isEmpty() && !block.isEmpty()) {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName")
                    .whereEqualTo("block", block);
        } else {
            return db.collection("Student")
                    .orderBy("fullName");
        }
    }
}
```

At first firestore returns 20 students (which is correct) but then I did a filter and return all BSCS students so firestore now returns 5 students (which is correct) but then I changed student1 fullName and now firestore returns 20 students (which is incorrect). I think firestore reset the Query information onDataChanged()

Comment: maybe your query is related s.t you changed. Please upload your query code.

Comment: @KiluSs I've uploaded the query code. Please help me

Comment: Have you tried to implement [getItemCount()](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/5b6c9f01f5a674d754d8e9b1242197fe040086e7/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java#L95)?

Comment: @AlexMamo I've solve this issue just by creating my own callback inside my custom adapter

Comment: Good to hear that ;)